# Extract all tables from web page in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I want to get all the tables from web page in python, but my code is showing only one of table not all. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

res = requests.get("http://www.findchips.com/search/PCB")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print( tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
```

Comment: why not just `dfs = pd.read_html(url)`? It will give you 42 tables back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables
# do your stuff for every table
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print( tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
```